# Triple Boot Windows , Windows 8 and Ubuntu 11.10 with Grub?

Tags: 11.10, installation, grub2, windows-8, dual-boot

I have Windows 7 and Ubuntu 11.10 installed. If I wanted to install Windows 8 and triple boot with Grub running the show, how difficult would it be? Installing another OS is the easy part. It's the configuring Grub I am clueless about.

Any thoughts (and directions!) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Win8 will likely override GRUB so it won't be possible to boot into Ubuntu. Keep Ubuntu LiveCD handy :) The process will include booting from the LiveCD after installing Windows and then using one of the methods of restoring GRUB described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling_GRUB2)

After you make your Ubuntu bootable again, you run `update-grub` to regenerate the config - after this the new Windows install should appear in the boot menu. If it doesn't then you'll need to edit the config manually following the instructions at the link above.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is quite possible, that when You install Win8, just

```
grub-update
```

will be enough. If not You can always configure it manually. It's not that hard :]

But on a second tought: Why won't You use virtualization? Win8 is in early beta so it might cause some problems.

Comment: I assume you mean that I should the install disk and run that in Terminal?

Comment: What do You mean? After installing Win8 on other partition or other hard drive, from Ubuntu in terminal You should run that command.

Comment: If I install Win 8, doesn't that remove Grub?  I assume I would need the live CD to access a Terminal to update Grub.  As for vt, my understanding is Win 8 is quite sluggish in vt which is why I would opt for a triple boot option.

Comment: It might. Well I would recommend virtualization. I have Win8 on VirtualBox and it works quite nice.