# Can i Install Windows 8 along with already dual Windows 7 & Ubuntu 12.04 ?? Does it affects boot Menu?

Tags: bootloader, dual-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Triple Boot Windows , Windows 8 and Ubuntu 11.10 with Grub?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103933/triple-boot-windows-windows-8-and-ubuntu-11-10-with-grub)

I am already having dual boot Windows 7 & Ubuntu 12.04 in their dedicated hard disk space . Windows 7 was installed in C drive firstly (a dedicated space of 340GB for windows) & then Ubuntu was installed in its dedicated space of 125GB (i have 500GB hard disk). now i want to install windows 8 in D drive of Windows partition. does installation of windows 8 will affect my already setup dual boot OS ?? do i encounter any problem on startup boot menu ??

Pls help me i want windows 8 on my Laptop..

2nd gen core i5 processor, 6GB, 500Gb, Intel HD Graphics

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion to your problem: Virtual machines. :)

Windows 8 will recognize your windows 7 installation but won't recognize the ubuntu installation. It's best to first install all of your windows installations from old to new. for example: first windows XP, second windows 7 and then windows 8 and afterwards your linux. Linux always recognizes the windows os and will install over or next to it. That's up to you.

But, and therefore I suggested it, there's another option: virtual machines. I have a windows 7 running, with several (7 to be exact) virtual machines. And I have got to say, it works for me. I can access all my linux installations inside windows. For example: I can have windows running with 2 virtual linux machines. And by installing them virtually I can test connecting from windows to linux. I can install virtual servers (Samba and Apache) and test how they work with windows. If something goes wrong with one linux machine I can always go back to a snapshot I made, without reinstalling the whole thing.

There are several programs for doing this, like Virtualbox and VMware (these are the best known.) Setting up a virtual machine is very easy and it installs faster then a normal installation. You can add as many network cards as you like, you can choose how much memory you want to dedicate to each machine, you can set up the size of the HDD,... Virtual machines are very flexible, and that's why I think it would be a great option in this case.

But that's just my suggestion. Hope I could help you.:)

Comment: @EliahKagan I still feel this is more of a suggestion than a real answer. Triple boot on raw hardware is simply very different compared to running them as virtual machines. Not only hardware requirements are different, but also some abilities like raw graphics access for gaming, etc.

Comment: @gertvdijk This might be a suggestion. I'm not forcing him to act on this answer. I just stated what works for me. And I know my first answer was a bit to short, so I explained why I suggested this. But as I said this is my answer not the answer. :)